# WSO2 ESB HL7 handling

Tags: hl7, wso2-esb

I am currently building a mediation flow working on HL7s. I receive HL7s via MLLP. Then I clone the message into 2 parts. In the first one I filter on the type of message that works well. Then I just want to forward the message to an MLLP system but I don't see how to do it. In the second part, I want to write the HL7 in a directory. I can create a file but the content is written in xml and not in hl7 format.
Here is the content of my sequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="NormalSeq" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <propertyGroup>
        <property expression="//hl7:MSG.1[1]/text()" name="HL7_TYPE" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v2xml"/>
        <property expression="//hl7:MSG.2[1]/text()" name="HL7_SUBTYPE" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v2xml"/>
    </propertyGroup>
    <clone>
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <log>
                    <property name="ROUTE" value="MED_EQUIPMENT"/>
                </log>
                <filter regex="true" source="get-property('HL7_TYPE') = 'ADT' and get-property('HL7_SUBTYPE') = 'A04'">
                    <then>
                        <log>
                            <property name="FOR_MED_EQU" value="YES"/>
                        </log>
                        <call>
                            <endpoint key="HL7MEDEQU"/>
                        </call>
                    </then>
                    <else>
                        <log>
                            <property name="FOR_MED_EQU" value="NO"/>
                        </log>
                        <drop/>
                    </else>
                </filter>
            </sequence>
        </target>
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <propertyGroup>
                    <property name="ROUTE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="LAB"/>
                    <property expression="fn:concat(get-property('SYSTEM_DATE', 'yyyyMMdd.HHmmssSSS'), '.hl7')" name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
                    <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
                </propertyGroup>
                <log>
                    <property expression="get-property('transport.vfs.ReplyFileName')" name="FILENAME"/>
                    <property expression="fn:concat(get-property('SYSTEM_DATE', 'yyyyMMdd.HHmmssSSS'), '.hl7')" name="SYSDATE"/>
                </log>
                <send>
                    <endpoint key="HL7_Lab_EP"/>
                </send>
            </sequence>
        </target>
        <target>
            <sequence/>
        </target>
    </clone>
</sequence>
```

here is the code of the inbound-endoint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inboundEndpoint name="HL7GW" onError="FaultSeq" protocol="hl7" sequence="NormalSeq" suspend="false" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="inbound.hl7.Port">2000</parameter>
        <parameter name="inbound.hl7.AutoAck">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="inbound.hl7.TimeOut">10000</parameter>
        <parameter name="inbound.hl7.CharSet">UTF-8</parameter>
        <parameter name="inbound.hl7.ValidateMessage">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="inbound.hl7.BuildInvalidMessages">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="inbound.hl7.PassThroughInvalidMessages">true</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

and here is the endpoints code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="HL7_ECG_EP" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <address uri="hl7://localhost:2001">
        <suspendOnFailure>
            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
            <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
        </suspendOnFailure>
        <markForSuspension>
            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
        </markForSuspension>
    </address>
</endpoint>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="HL7_Lab_EP" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <address uri="vfs:file:///c:/temp/hl7">
        <suspendOnFailure>
            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
            <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
        </suspendOnFailure>
        <markForSuspension>
            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
        </markForSuspension>
    </address>
</endpoint>
```

To summarize, I would like to:
1. Send HL7s in MLLP on a system external to ESB
2. Save these HL7s in a directory in the HL7 format and not XML as shown below:

```
MSH|^~\&|HL7Soup|Instance1|HL7Soup|Instance2|200808181126|SECURITY|ADT^A04|MSG00001|P|2.5.1
EVN|A01-|200808181123|
PID||77291|PATID1234^9^55A||Smith^Willian^A^III||19720415|M-||2106-3|555 Upper Harbour Rd^^Springfield^NC^3401-540|NN|(919)479-4354|(919)371-654~(919)377-3455||S|AGN|PATID12345001^2^R10|1234567890|A-84334^NC
NK1|1|Smith^Barbara^K|SPO|||||20011105
NK1|1|Smith^Bill^A|FTH
PV1|1|I|2000^2012^01||||004777^LEBAUER^SIDNEY^J.|||SUR||-||1|A0-
AL1|1||^PENICILLIN||PRODUCES HIVES~RASH
AL1|2||^CAT DANDER
DG1|001|I9|1550|MAL NEO LIVER, PRIMARY|20080501103005|F||
PR1|2234|M11|111^CODE151|COMMON PROCEDURES|200809081123
ROL|45^RECORDER^ROLE MASTER LIST|AD|CP|34622^SMITH^JILL|200805011201
GT1|1122|1519|BILL^GATES^A
IN1|001|A357|1234|BCMD|||||132987
IN2|ID1551001|SSN12345678
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your approach seems to be fine. Could you confirm whether you've enabled the HL7 transport sender and the HL7 message formatter in the axis2.xml? (Reference: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/HL7+Transport) HL7 message being stored as XML can be due to HL7 formatter not enabled.

Comment: @ThishaniLucas I omit to say that i'm using WSO2 Integration Studio 7.0.0 I check the axis2.xml and there is no hl7 transport and receiver. Since there is no section to uncomment, i don't know what is the xml to insert in the axis2.xml. Where can i find the xml code for enabling hl7 transpot and receiver?

Comment: You can refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/HL7+Transport#HL7Transport-Enablingthetransport

Comment: @ThishaniLucas I added the needed section to the axis2.xml of intergation studio but when i run the project (run as -> Run on micro integrator), integration studio change de axis2.xml back to it's previous version... The first line of the console is [2019-10-31 11:43:37,404]  WARN {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Configurations Changed in :conf\axis2\axis2.xml

Answer (score 0):

After a few tests, I finally managed to make the recording of the hl7 message work as a file in hl7 format and not XML.

I had to deploy the ESB solution on a server (WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.5.0) and activate the HL7s in the axis2.xml file on that server.

For some reason I don't know, if I modify the axis2.xml file of WSO2 Integration Studio, as soon as I launch the solution in WSO2 Integration Studio, the configuration file returns to its previous state.
This happens regardless of the modification in the file. Even if you add a simple comment, the file returns directly to its original version.

Comment: I would like to know if this is a normal behavior of WSO2 Integration Studio and if so why?  If not, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Yes, this is the expected behavior in EI 7. With the EI 7, wso2 has introduced a new method of modifying the configurations using deployement.toml. This enables users to get all the configurations in one location and thus the relevant configurations will be updated from the deployement.toml during run time. Please refer [1] on how the configurations must be made in the EI 7 version.

[1]-https://medium.com/technology-in-essence/configuring-wso2-micro-integrator-with-single-toml-configuration-model-ec1052716ed0